# Python Flask SocketIO Session Errors

Tags: python, linux, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-socketio, secret-key

### BACKGROUND

I am working on a Python/Flask/SocketIO app that is sourced from a few different places and being developed in Linux

> **Purpose:** Login/Registration Functionality
> **Title:** Python Flask Authentication Tutorial - Learn Flask Login
> **By:** Arpan Neupane
> **Link:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71EU8gnZqZQ
> **Link**: https://github.com/arpanneupane19/Python-Flask-Authentication-Tutorial

> **Purpose**: HTML Sidebar with Toggle Functionality
> **Title:** simple-sidebar-flask
> **By:** jpf5046
> **Link**: https://github.com/jpf5046/simple-sidebar-flask/tree/main/simple-sidebar-flask

> **Purpose**: SocketIO Chat Functionality
> **Title:** RealTime Chat App - Flask, SocketIO
> **By:** Mohit Singh (msindev)
> **Link**: https://github.com/msindev/Chat-App-Flask-SocketIO

### PROBLEM

I experience any of the following depending on how I try to fix the app

- An error about the secret key not being set
- The app home loads, allows login/registration, redirects to dashboard that has a chat app in the sidebar but sending chat messages do not post.

In my experimenting, I've found that have removing the use of *from flask_session import Session* gets me around the secret key errors but leaves me with the socketIO unresponsiveness.

### APP CODE

To start, I'll post my project below. I'm certainly willing to edit the post to show additional information & specific errors. I keep it simple to start, hopefully what I post will spark some ideas, thanks!

#### app.py

```
''' Begin : Import source dependencies '''
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_session import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, leave_room, emit
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, session
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, EqualTo, ValidationError
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user

''' End : Import source dependencies '''



''' Begin : Init app and support instances '''
# Initialize app instance
app = Flask( __name__ )

# Set the app secret key for data encrpytion
app.config[ 'SECRET_KEY '] = 'thisisasecretkey'
#app.secret_key = 'thisisasecretkey'
app.config[ 'WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY' ] = "anothersecretkey"

# Connect the app to the Session manager 
sess = Session()
sess.init_app( app )

# Configure the app to timeout
app.config[ 'SESSION_PERMANENT' ] = False

# Set the database path
app.config[ 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' ] = 'sqlite:///database.db'

# Connect the app to the socketIO
socketio = SocketIO( app, manage_session=True )

# Connect the app and database
db = SQLAlchemy( app )

# Connect the app and the encryption engine
bcrypt = Bcrypt( app )

# Initialize the login manager
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app( app )
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

''' End : Init-> app and support instances '''



''' Begin : Callback/emitter to handle chat room entry '''
@socketio.on('join', namespace='\chat')
def join(message):

    # Track the send time
    timeStamp = datetime.now().strftime( '%H:%M:%S' )

    # Join the room
    join_room( session[ 'room' ] )

    # Emit chat board update
    emit( 'status', { 'msg': timeStamp + ' : [ ' + session[ 'username' ]  + ' ] : ' + ' has entered the chat' }, 
          room=session[ 'room' ] )

''' End : Callback/emitter to handle chat room entry '''



''' Begin : Callback/emitter to handle chat room messaging '''
@socketio.on('text', namespace='\chat')
def text(message):

    print('\n\n\n*** Message = ', message, '\n\n\n*****\n\n\n')

    # Track the send time
    timeStamp = datetime.now().strftime( '%H:%M:%S' )

    # Emit chat board update
    emit( 'message', { 'msg': timeStamp + ' : [ ' + session[ 'username' ]  + ' ] : ' + message['msg'] },
          room=session[ 'room' ] )

''' End : Callback/emitter to handle chat room messaging '''



''' Begin : Callback for Login Manager to user from database '''
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user( user_id ):
    return User.query.get( int( user_id ) )

''' End : Callback for Login Manager to user from database '''



''' Begin : Class definition to handle user profile/session '''
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    # Database ID for user
    id = db.Column( db.Integer, primary_key=True )

    # User name and password columns for database
    username = db.Column( db.String( 20 ), nullable=False, unique=True )
    password = db.Column( db.String( 100 ), nullable=False )

''' End : Class definition to handle user profile/session '''



''' Begin : Class definition to handle user registration entry field requirements '''
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):

    # Spec for user name
    username = StringField( validators=[ InputRequired(), Length( min=4, max=20 ) ], 
                            render_kw={ "placeholder": "Username" } )

    # Spec for password
    password = PasswordField( validators=[ InputRequired(), Length( min=5, max=20 ) ], 
                              render_kw={ "placeholder": "Password" } )

    # Spec for password confirmation
    confirm_password = PasswordField( validators=[ InputRequired(), Length( min=5, max=20 ), EqualTo( 'password' ) ], 
                                      render_kw={ "placeholder": "Password" } )

    # Label and callback for registration button
    submit = SubmitField( 'Register' )

    # Method to validate unique user name
    def validate_username(self, username):

        # Query the user database by username
        existing_user_username = User.query.filter_by( username=username.data ).first()

        # If user name already exists
        if existing_user_username:

            # Raise error to user
            raise ValidationError( 'That username already exists. Please choose a different one.' )

''' End : Class definition to handle user registration entry field requirements '''



''' Begin : Class definition to handle user name and password entry field requirements '''
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):

    # Spec for user name
    username = StringField( validators=[ InputRequired(), Length( min=4, max=20 ) ], 
                            render_kw={ "placeholder": "Username" } )

    # Spec for password
    password = PasswordField( validators=[ InputRequired(), Length( min=5, max=20 ) ], 
                              render_kw={ "placeholder": "Password" } )

    # Label and callback for login button
    submit = SubmitField( 'Login' )

''' End : Class definition to handle user name and password entry field requirements '''



''' Begin : Route to load login authentication system '''
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template( 'home.html' )

''' Begin : Route to load login authentication system '''




''' Begin : Route to loading login-only home screen '''
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    # Initialize login form
    form = LoginForm()

    # Validate user on submit attempt
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # Query database for user 
        user = User.query.filter_by( username=form.username.data ).first()

        # If user found
        if user:

            # If password correct
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash( user.password, form.password.data ):

                # Signal successful user login
                login_user(user)

                # Track the user name for the chat board
                session[ 'username' ] = form.username.data

                # Set a single chat room key
                session[ 'room' ] = 'ChatBoard'

                # Redirect user to login-only page
                return redirect( url_for( 'dashboard' ) )

    # Bad login attempt, serve login page with form data
    return render_template( 'login.html', form=form )

''' End : Route to loading login-only home screen '''



''' Begin : Route to handle user registration '''
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

    # Initialize a registration form object
    form = RegisterForm()

    # Validate on submit attempt
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # Get password field and encrypt
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash( form.password.data )

        # Initialize a new user instance
        new_user = User( username=form.username.data, password=hashed_password )

        # Stage the user/password to the user database
        db.session.add( new_user )

        # Commit the user/password
        db.session.commit()

        # Redirect user to login
        return redirect( url_for( 'login' ) )

    # User login failed, redirect to register : TODO -> check: alert on bad user OR pass, redirect if on fail BOTH
    return render_template( 'register.html', form=form )

''' End : Route to handle user registration '''



''' Begin : Route to handle user logout '''
@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#@login_required
def logout():

    # Signal logout to login manager
    logout_user()

    # Redirect user to login screen
    return redirect( url_for( 'login' ) )

''' End : Route to handle user logout '''



''' Begin : Route to loading login-only page '''
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#@login_required
def dashboard():

    # Render dashboard
    return render_template( 'dashboard.html' )

''' End : Route to loading login-only page '''



''' Begin : Entry point '''
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Serve app to network
    socketio.run( app, debug=True, use_reloader=True )

''' Begin : Entry point '''
```

#### login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Login Page</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.password }}
        {{ form.submit }}
    </form>

    <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Don't have an account? Sign Up</a>
</body>

</html>
```

#### register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Register Page</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.password }}
        {{ form.confirm_password }}
        {{ form.submit }}
    </form>

    <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Already have an account? Log In</a>
</body>

</html>
```

#### dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Live Study Tracker</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/socket.io.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var socket;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/chat');
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('join', {});
            });
            socket.on('status', function(data) {
                $('#chat').val($('#chat').val() + '<' + data.msg + '>\n');
                $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
            });
            socket.on('message', function(data) {
                $('#chat').val($('#chat').val() + data.msg + '\n');
                $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
            });
            $('#send').click(function(e) {
                    text = $('#text').val();
                    $('#text').val('');
                    socket.emit('text', {msg: text});
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-heading">Chat Board</div>

              <body class="text-center">                
                <div class="chatwindow">
                  <textarea id="chat" cols="70" rows="10" placeholder="No messages yet. Start one..."></textarea><br /><br />
                  <input type="text" id="text" size="60" placeholder="Enter your message here" />
                  <button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button><br /><br />
                </div>
              </body>

        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Chat</button>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">

                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('logout')}}">Logout</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
                <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on
                    larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
                <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is
                    optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which
                    will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```